# C# console basic UI with timer

Tags: c#, timer, console-application

I am making a basic Console application (unfortunately this is a must) that shows the time and a very basic interface where a user can enter an option.  When they do, the UI updates with relevant new data to display and allows further input and so on.  All the while, a live clock with seconds is shown at the top.

What I am basically doing is redrawing the whole UI every second and attempting to listen to the user input to direct how the UI is drawn next time around.  How do I manage the user input while redrawing the UI?  Is there a better way?

Here is the whole (very cut down verion of) program:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;

namespace TimerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool useStartUI = false;
        static string currentInput = "";
        static Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DrawUI);
            aTimer.Interval = 1000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
            Console.ReadLine();
            currentInput = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void DrawUI(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("currentInput = " + currentInput);
            if (currentInput == "A")
            {
                useStartUI = true;
            } else
            {
                useStartUI = false;
            }
            if (!useStartUI)
            {
                DisplayStartUI();
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayCurrentUI();
            }
        }
        private static void DisplayStartUI()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("DisplayStartUI - " +     DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt"));
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'B' to switch to CurrentUI");
            Console.ReadLine();
            currentInput = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static void DisplayCurrentUI()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("DisplayCurrentUI - " +     DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt"));
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'A' to switch to StartUI");
            Console.ReadLine();
            currentInput = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment I have the `Console.ReadLine();` right after the timer is fired, if I don't then the application opens and closes straight away.  The other two `Console.ReadLine();` are ignored completely but it is at these points I would have expected user input to be recorded.

Comment: Look at the documentation for the `Console` class. It has properties and methods to get and set the cursor position, to get the (current) size of the console window, etc. Utilizing those features and information, it should become easy for you to only write to those areas of our console UI that needs to be updated. Also, if you don't want your program exiting, you will need to prevent your Main method from exiting (exiting the Main method means the program will end). How you will/can prevent the Main method from exiting is your choice and ultimately depends on the requirements of your app logic

Comment: (Side note: Exiting the main method does not _always_ mean the program will exit. More accurately, the program will exit when the _last_ foreground thread ends. Now, in your console application here, you only have one foreground thread - the thread running the Main method. Thus, exiting the Main method will end the only foreground thread in your program, thus exiting the progam. If you were to write a progam that would utilize multiple foreground threads, the program wouldn't exit until every single foreground thread has ended. No, i am not saying you should use multiple foreground threads...)

Comment: Ok, I think I get you.  So maybe allow the timer for the clock to exist on another thread and have it update only the top portion of the console window (say the first 3 lines).  Any other update to the UI is done 'statically'.  The only issue would be when Console.Clear() is fired and the clock UI will take a short while to update meaning the UI may look a bit 'clunky'?

Comment: Why would you clear the whole console if you just want to update a rather small part of it? Also, this approach might suffer from undesired side effects: What if the user is in the process of typing in some text/data/whatever and in just that moment that timer fires and your program begins to move the cursor or clear the console in an attempt to update the UI while the user is typing? You will have to think through your application scenario and logic thoroughly, identify conflict scenarios such as the one i outlined here and validate and test them...

Comment: In the end, depending on what you want/need your application to do while the user can possibly enter data/text/whatever determines whether you can use Console.ReadLine or not. In the worst case, you might have to write your own input routine that would only rely on Console.ReadKey to achieve a robust behavior for user input while simultaneously allowing UI updates without disrupting/affecting user input...

Comment: That's kind of what I feel the whole problem revolves around.  Allowing the user to input their selection whenever they want while having the UI update (the time in thise case) without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I was over thinking this and @elgonzo pointed me in the right direction.  I now just have the timer display on one line and clear other lines as and when I need them.  I have a basic working example that I will expand my main program into.  It appears to do exactly what I need (obviously missing validation and functionality) please comment if this can be improved upon:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;

namespace TimerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool appOpen = true;
        static bool useStartUI = false;
        static string currentInput = "";
        static Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt"));
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DrawClock);
            aTimer.Interval = 1000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

            while (appOpen) // to keep the application running and give a possible exit - will expand this
            {
                DrawUI();
            }
        }
        #region UI region
        static void DrawClock(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("DrawClock - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss     tt"));
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 7);
        }
        static void DrawUI()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("currentInput = " + currentInput);
            if (currentInput == "A" || currentInput == "a")
            {
                useStartUI = true;
            }
            else if (currentInput == "B" || currentInput == "b")
            {
                useStartUI = false;
            }
            if (useStartUI)
            {
                DisplayStartUI();
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayCurrentUI();
            }
        }
        private static void DisplayStartUI()
        {
            CleanUI();
            Console.WriteLine("DisplayStartUI");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'B' to switch to CurrentUI");

            ConsoleKeyInfo keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 7);
            Console.WriteLine("You pressed {0}", keyPressed.KeyChar);
            currentInput = keyPressed.KeyChar.ToString();
            if (keyPressed.KeyChar.ToString() == "b")
            {
                DrawUI();
            }
        }
        private static void DisplayCurrentUI()
        {
            CleanUI();
            Console.WriteLine("DisplayCurrentUI");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'A' to switch to StartUI");
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 7);
            Console.WriteLine("You pressed {0}", keyPressed.KeyChar);
            currentInput = keyPressed.KeyChar.ToString();
            if (keyPressed.KeyChar.ToString() == "a")
            {
                DrawUI();
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region functional methods
        public static void CleanUI()
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 5);
            ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 6);
            ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 7);
            ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 5);
        }
        public static void ClearCurrentConsoleLine()
        {
            int currentLineCursor = Console.CursorTop;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
            Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentLineCursor);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```